# How to concatenate a JS variable in an HTML script?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I do something like this?

```
var counter = SomeJSFunctionThatReturnsAvalue();

<tr><td> <input type="file" name="file-upload"+"_counter" id="file-upload" /></tr></td>
```

Can I do that? I need to append an underscore and an incremented number to the name.

Also, an off-topic question - that function above returns the value of an input type, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-input-type" value="2" />
```

Is the value "2" a number that I can use for math operations? If not, how can I make it one?

Comment: `"_counter"` is a string. If you want the underscore and the _value_ of counter, you want `"_" + counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go fella.

```
<head>
<script>
function test($count) {
document.getElementById("test1").setAttribute("name","file-upload_" + $count);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>some content</p>
<input id="test1" type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" value="2"/>
<p>some other content</p>
<script>test(1);</script>
</body>
```

Your `SomeJSFunctionThatReturnsAvalue();` would pass it to `test()` function.

to get the value of "2" from your second question for use in a math function, just do:

```
var value = document.getElementById("test1").getAttribute("value");
document.write(parseInt(value, 10) + 3);
```

which returns 5.

Comment: Note these changes occur in the DOM. So you can scroll over the page and select "view selection source" to see them take effect (you won't see the changes in "view source").

Comment: Hey, I cant get it by element since there are number of file input types, they dont have unique ids since they are dynamically created, I want when i create them they have unique name.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name using `.setAttribute("name", theNameUwantToChangeTo);`:

```
function changeName(number){

    var ele =  document.getElementById("file-upload");
    ele.setAttribute("name",  b.getAttribute("name")+ "_" + number);
}
changeName(number);
```

To get the value, just `.value`:

```
function getV(){

    return document.getElementById("file-upload").value;
}
var number = getV();
```

In case it does not return int, use `parseInt()`

```
function getV(){

    return parseInt(document.getElementById("file-upload").value);
}
var number = getV();
```

Comment: I think you did not get my question sir.

Answer (score 1):

To append the return value of your function to the name of the input tag, you can assign it to the name attribute of the input.

```
var counter = SomeJSFunctionThatReturnsAvalue();
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-upload');

fileUpload.name = fileUpload.name + "_" + counter;
```

You can get the type of a variable by using "typeof"

```
typeof myValue; // "string"
```

You can change this to an integer by using the parseInt() function.

```
var intValue = parseInt(myValue, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would benefit from looking into [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org) or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/about/) if you are trying to do things like this. They can do data binding so that you can make readable and dynamic code just like what you are trying to create in your question.

If not that^ then this:

I saw you mentioned in a comment that you are dynamically creating the list. That is where you should be assigning the correct name with the counter (assuming there's no desire for counter to change dynamically. If there is a dynamic change then tell us what events are doing the change) Could you show us the code that is doing that please?